# Login to google using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-oauth, google-finance

I have been trying for some time now to login to my google account and download a file from it **without using any external libraries**.
I am specifically talking about Google Finance (https://www.google.com/finance). 
All I want to do is login, and download my portfolio (after you sign in and go to the Portfolios tab, there is a link saying: Download to spreadsheet).
But I can't get it to work.

I have seen several posts here regarding similar problems but none of them worked for me.

This is the code I have now:

```
import urllib, urllib2, cookielib

#Gets the current directory
output_path = os.getcwd()

def make_url(ticker_symbol):
    return base_url + ticker_symbol

def make_filename(ticker_symbol):
    return output_path + "\\" + ticker_symbol + ".csv"

# Login page for Google Finance
login_url = "https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=finance&passive=1209600&continue=https://www.google.com/finance&followup=https://www.google.com/finance"

# Google Finance portfolio Download url (works after you signed in)
download_url = "https://www.google.com/finance/portfolio?pid=1&output=csv&action=viewt&ei=ypZyUZi_EqGAwAP5Vg"

username = 'my_username'
password = 'my_password'

cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
login_data = urllib.urlencode({'username' : username, 'j_password' : password})
opener.open(login_url, login_data)

# Download the file
try:
    urllib.urlretrieve(download_url, make_filename("My_portfolio"))
except urllib.ContentTooShortError as e:
    outfile = open(make_filename("My_portfolio"), "w")
    outfile.write(e.content)
    outfile.close()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: The file is being downloaded, but its empty. Like when you try to download your portfolio using the specified link, without signing in.

Comment: You need to log in by POSTing to `https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLoginAuth`.  The url you are going to is just the login page, you need to actually simulate the login form submission.  Use FireBug or Google Dev Tools Network panel to get more details on how to make the login call.

Comment: I did find a script that uses ServiceLoginAuth but it didn't work either.
This is the script I'm talking about http://everydayscripting.blogspot.co.il/2009/10/python-fixes-to-google-login-script.html

Comment: Didn't work how?  What error did you get?  Did you have a `getpass` implementation?  You can't just expect to copy/paste code and have it work, you need to know what it is actually doing.

Answer (score 0):

The author of the [script](http://everydayscripting.blogspot.co.il/2009/10/python-fixes-to-google-login-script.html) you mention has since updated the said script(s). These scripts are designed specifically for gVoice, but can be used as an example for your needs with gFinance I'm sure.

The new scripts are found at [GitHub](https://github.com/hillmanov/gvoice).